# Can a PHP class property be equal to another class property?

Tags: php, class, properties

I want to do this:

```
class MyClass {
   var $array1 = array(3,4);
   var $array2 = self::$array1;
}
```

and `$array2` doesn't work.

Do you have a solution/trick to make a class property equal to another class property?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [`PHP Manual`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a **variable**, a class member or a function call.

What you COULD do is:

```
class MyClass {
    var $array1 = array(3,4);
    var $array2 = array();

    function MyClass() {
        $this->array2 = $this->array1;
    }
}
```

The function `MyClass` (or `__construct` if you are in PHP5) will be called every time a new object is created, so any instances of `MyClass` would have an `array2` property that has the same value as its `array1` property.

```
$myclass = new MyClass();
print_r($myclass->array1); // outputs Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 ) 
print_r($myclass->array2); // outputs Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 )
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to PHP, but the answer from Paolo seems to be just initializing the **values** to be the same in the constructor, but that doesn't actually make both variables reference the same content.  How about this:

```
class MyClass {
    var $array1 = array(3,4);
    var $array2 = array();

    function MyClass() {
        $this->array2 = &$this->array1;
    }
}

$myclass = new MyClass();
print_r($myclass->array1); // outputs Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 ) 
print_r($myclass->array2); // outputs Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 )
echo "<br />";
$myclass->array1[0] = 1;
$myclass->array2[1] = 2;
print_r($myclass->array1); // outputs Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) 
print_r($myclass->array2); // outputs Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

With the addition of the reference, **both** class property values change when either is changed.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I didn't get the impression from his question that he wanted them referenced to one another, just that he wanted them to originally be the same.

Comment: Oh, OK, then I misunderstood the question!

Answer (score 0):

Both your answers, Paolo and notruthless, are excellent, thank you very much!

If I want the two properties to keep in sync:

```
function MyClass() {
    $this->array2 = &$this->array1;
}
```

If I want the two arrays to have identical values initially but then want to modify them individually, I remove the '&':

```
function MyClass() {
    $this->array2 = $this->array1;
}
```

Comment: Just make your code PHP 5 friendly naming your constructor function simply __construct() instead of MyClass().