# Static property accesses static property in PHP

Tags: java, php, parsing, properties, static

While creating an application, i came across a situation where i had a static variable.

let's say it is:

```
public static name = "abdul ahad";
```

down the line, somewhere i had another static variable called **user** which accesses static variable name as defined above.

```
public static user = self::$name;
```

> Note: those properties are members of the same class.

Doing this, gives the following error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$XXX' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or class (T_CLASS) in C:\xxxx\xxx\xxx.php on line xx

The same concept holds true for **Java** as shown below.

```
public static int i = 5;
public static int j = Main.i;   

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(String.format("Static j was : %d", Main.j));
```

So, i want to know whether it is possible in PHP & what i am doing wrong with syntax. If it is not, then would you care to explain why ?

Comment: No, you can't initialise a property based on another property in PHP. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477066/can-a-php-class-property-be-equal-to-another-class-property

Comment: i can initialize a property based on another property. it is right. like int a = 5; int b = a; this is allowed. But problems happen with static variables.

Comment: your link to the thread doesn't deal with static stuff.

Comment: Whether it's static or not doesn't make any difference. Class properties can only be initialised to a constant value, or a basic expression (as of PHP 5.6). You can't reference any other variables (globals, properties, anything).

Comment: not working with php 7.1 as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The static declarations are *evaluated compile-time* so you cannot initialize a static property using another variable (doesn't matter if it's static or not).

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant before PHP 5.6; expressions are not allowed. In PHP 5.6 and later, the same rules apply as [const](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php) expressions: some limited expressions are possible, provided they can be evaluated at compile time.

**Note**: the error message you have posted is most likely from some code you didn't share with us. Also, you have another error in your code:

```
public static user = self::$name;
//            ^
// the actual error
```

It should produce the following error message:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'user' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in ...

Every variable in PHP must have `$` (the dollar sign) prefix so the proper property declaration should look like the following:

```
public static $user = self::$name;
```

But, as I wrote above, you cannot initialize a static property using a variable so it would produce the following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in ...

Just for the comparison, the error message from your post:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$XXX' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or class (T_CLASS) in ...